# ElasticSearch order by number of matches in nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Complete beginner here, quite possibly trying to do the impossible.
I have the following structure that I would like to store in Elasticsearch:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "code" : "03f3301c-4089-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33",
    "countries" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Netherlands"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "United Kingdom"
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Scanned"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Secured"
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name" : "Cleared"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have complete control over how it will be stored, so the structure can change, but it should contain all these fields in some form.
I’d like to be able to query this data over `countries` and `tags` in such way that all those items having at least one match are returned, ordered by number of matches. If at all possible I’d prefer not to do a full text search.

For example:

```
id, code, country ids, tag ids
1,  ...,  [1, 2, 3],   [1]
2,  ...,  [1],         [1, 2, 3]
```

For the question: `"which of these was in country 1 or has tag 1 or has tag 2"`, should return:

```
2, ..., [1], [1, 2, 3]
1, ..., [1, 2, 3], [1]
```

In this order, because the second row matches more sub-queries in the above disjunction.

In essence, I’d like to replicate this SQL query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, COUNT(p.id) FROM packages p
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.package_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN countries c ON c.package_id = p.id
WHERE t.id IN (1, 2, 3) OR c.id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY COUNT(p.id);
```

I’m using ElasticSearch 2.4.5 if that matters.

Hopefully I was clear enough. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `countries` and `tags` to be of type `nested`. Also, you need to take control of the scoring with `function_score` give a `weight` of `1` for the queries inside the function_score and also play with `boost_mode` and `score_mode`. In the end you can use this query:

```
GET /nested/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }, 
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "tags",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "tags.id": 1
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "tags",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "tags.id": 2
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "countries",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "countries.id": 1
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace", 
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

For a more complete test case, I am also providing the mapping and test data:

```
PUT nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "countries": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST nested/test/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"Foo Bar","tags":[{"id":2,"name":"My Tag 5"},{"id":3,"name":"My Tag 7"}],"countries":[{"id":1,"name":"USA"}]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"Foo Bar","tags":[{"id":3,"name":"My Tag 6"}],"countries":[{"id":1,"name":"USA"},{"id":2,"name":"UK"},{"id":3,"name":"UAE"}]}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"Foo Bar","tags":[{"id":1,"name":"My Tag 4"},{"id":3,"name":"My Tag 1"}],"countries":[{"id":3,"name":"UAE"}]}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"name":"Foo Bar","tags":[{"id":1,"name":"My Tag 1"},{"id":2,"name":"My Tag 4"},{"id":3,"name":"My Tag 2"}],"countries":[{"id":2,"name":"UK"},{"id":3,"name":"UAE"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! One small change I had to do was set the 'weight' of all the functions to 2 and add a 'min_score' of 2, because if the document didn't match any of the filters it would still get a 'score' of 1.